# how to read a specific timestamped log file when many timestamped log files are present

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier

I want to read a specific time stamped log file when many time stamped log files are present using java. Or is there any method so i can read presently created log file from some other method when that log file is created by other method?

Comment: What you have done so far ?

Comment: Please post code you have tried.

Comment: obviously you need a way to uniquely identify that log file maybe by timestamp or other unique way, it is not `java`-specific issue, rather a consistent naming issue

Comment: I have tried only accessing a log file. I have not tried to access particular time stamped log file because i don't know that. i searched in internet also what all i got is how to access a particular time stamped lines or messages in a log file.

Comment: yes there must be a unique way to identify the log files. i have used DailyRollingFileAppender to generate a time stamped log files. Those generated files are stored in one folder. If i want to access the currently generated time stamped log file when running some application how can i access that file.I am not aware of that file name which contains a log file generated time. Need a code for that or need to know any idea about how to do that.